# Contact Picker fails from URL in WebView but work in same URL in android chrome browser

Tags: webview, contacts, picker

I used the chrome contact Picker from glitch to view my phone contacts from my website in android chrome.

A WebView app using the same website as URL opens the contact Picker stage alright but fails to show phone contacts. Do I need certain permissions before using the API in android WebView?

Your help will be appreciated.